# Set value from json when return a string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

peoples.
I write the code and suddenly I have seen

```
"EmailMaximalLength": "Maximal length {{ val }} symbols",
```

So, for example I wanna call this string by key and how to determine the value? Maybe somebody knows.)

```
Console.log(EmailMaximalLength)// i see Maximal length symbols
```

but I want Maximal length 100 or 222 or 333 symbols
How it works?)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, of course. But look

```
export const isMaximal = (maxLength = MAX_LENGTH) => (
    (value: string) => (value.length <= maxLength ? null : { name: 'registration.FieldMaxLength', prop: maxLength })
);
```

were `"FieldMaxLength": "Maximal length {{ val }} symbols",`
It works without store value onto the JSON)